# double call 'click' events in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a little problem with calling the 'click' function in input object. function assigns an event to the input:

```
function v_start() {
      $('#next').click(function(){
                    v_check();
      });
}
```

now in javascript files name.js and name2.js i have:
Copy code

```
$(function(){
      v_start();
});
```

is just an example, but in this case the function v_check will be called twice in one click input. is a condition or way to made ​​the event only once ? why the second event will not overwrite?

Comment: You probably attach an event handler twice. Add `alert(123);` there and see

Comment: If the snippet is both in `name.js` and `name2.js` it will attach the event handler twice, and therefore trigger the behavior twice.

Answer (score 3):

unbind and bind to be sure the event handler is only added once :

```
$("#mySelector").unbind("click").bind("click",myFunction)
```

if there are multiple event listeners :

```
var myFunction = function(e){ /// my code }

$("#mySelector").unbind("click",myFunction).bind("click",myFunction)
```

Comment: Or, if you're using jQuery 1.7+, use `.off()` and `.on()` rather than `.unbind()` and `.bind()`.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you handle an event in jQuery, it *adds* the handler to a list. There is no "overwriting".

A simple solution in this case to avoid having the event be assigned twice is to attach a data flag indicating the event has already been attached, like this for example.

```
function v_start() {
    if (!$('#next').data('click-handled')) {
        $('#next').data('click-handled', true).click(function(){
            v_check();
        });
    }
}
```

(You can also manually get a list of events and check if your function is there, but that's more quite a bit more complicated.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you call `v_start` twice in each of the files obviously you bind your event twice. You can do a simple check if `click` event is already handled like this:

```
function v_start() {
    var $next = $('#next');
    $next.data('events').click || $next.click(v_check);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$( ".mybutton" ).off('click').on('click', function() { 
// same code
});
```

This is the best solution for me, or too

```
$(".mybutton").unbind("click",myFunction).bind("click",myFunction)
```